# Grails: Join two tables using plain sql

Tags: sql, grails

I want to write sql query that joins two tables and return the result. Lets say we have two domain classes:

```
class Patient {
    static hasMany = [visits: Visit]
    String firstName
}
```

and

```
class Visit {
    static belongsTo = [patient: Patient]
    String visitNo
}
```

Now, how could I join those two tables using sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grails schema-export` to write the table DDL to `target/ddl.sql` - it will show you the table structure, foreign keys, etc.

In this case it'd be something like

```
select p.first_name, v.visit_no from patient p join visit v on v.patient_id=p.id
```